# How to find constant coefficients of Laplace equation solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, bessel-functions, sturm-liouville

I solved the Laplace equation in cylindrical coordinates with no $\theta$ dependence and got the solution $u(r,z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty K_n \sinh (\mu_nz)J_0(\mu_nr)$.

I have the conditions: $u(r,1) = f(r)$ and $u(1,z) = 0$.

Using both of these conditions I get that:

$u(r,1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty K_n \sinh (\mu_n)J_0(\mu_nr) = f(r)$

and

$u(1,z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty K_n \sinh (\mu_nz)J_0(\mu_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty K_n \sinh (\mu_nz)J_0(0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty K_n \sinh (\mu_nz)= 0$

This is because $\mu_n$ is a zero of $J_0$ and $J_0(0) = 1$.

How can I use these to obtain the coefficients $K_n$.

I feel like this would be easier if I was dealing with sin rather than sinh as then I would have a fourier sine series for which finding the coefficients is easy.

I also have the fact that $\int_0 ^1 J_0(\mu_mr)*J_0(\mu_nr)*r = \delta_{m,n}$. This is just the orthogonality of the eigenfunctions that come from the bessel equation.

Comment: If you had $\sin$ instead of $J_0$ you'd use the orthogonality of sines to extract the coefficients. Here you need to use the orthogonality of $J_0$. How to manipulate the equation for $f(r)$ to get the orthogonality relation on the left? Multiply by $J_0$ and integrate

Comment: @Sal ah ok I see what you are trying to do - but the orthogonality only applied with the weighted inner product, so with r being in the integral. So I would also have to multiply both sides by r as well right? And also is this not just equivalent to taking then either the weighted inner product of both sides, or multiplying both sides by r and then taking the inner product? thanks

Comment: Yes my mistake, you should multiply by $r$ as well. It is equivalent to taking the inner product with weight $r$

Comment: Thank you very much that was extremely helpful!

Comment: @Sal just to confirm I've done it right, I got k_n = 1/(sinh(mu_n)) * the weighted inner product of f(r) and j_0. Is that correct?

Comment: No problem. Yes that's correct